# How to pass props between routes in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

I want to send a variable as a prop from a route to another in vue.

I have a vue component, Champions, using a v-for and creating a new component called ChampionCard for each character in a JSON file, and binding the current champion each time.

In ChampionCard, I just show the name and image of the champion.
I want that, when clicking on a ChampionCard, you get redirected to another component called Champion with URL champions/:champion.

But I can't find a way to send the champion data between those 2 routes.

The Champions component :

```
<div class="champions">
    <ChampionCard v-bind:champion="champion" v-for="champion in champions" :key="champion.key"> 

    </ChampionCard>
 </div>
```

The ChampionCard component :

```
<article @click="redirectTo(champion)" class="champion">
      <img class="champion-icon" :src="champion.image" :alt="champion.name">
      <h2 class="champion-name"> {{ champion.name }} </h2>
</article>
```

```
redirectTo(champion) {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'champion', params: { champion: champion.key }})
    }
```

The above code is working as I get redirected to champions/championName, but I don't have access to my champion variable. What would be the best way to send it as a prop in Champion component ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access to your champion variable? You do, it's `this.$route.params.champion`. But it's just the `key`. You'd have to do a `global.variable.champions.find(champion => this.$route.params.champion)`. So my point is, you can't pass the fully structured object between routes. You'd have to be able to do a lookup to get it.

Comment: Thanks. Could you post this as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1):

My alternative is: While redirecting to `champions/:champion` route, just send the `id` of the `champion` (such as `champions/123`).

When you are redirecting to this route, you can store `champion` object in a global place (say `store`). So that you can lookup with id (123) when you're mounting the route.
One step further, if you cannot find the object in the global store, you can initiate a remote call. So that your route will not be broken if `123` is not in the store. (User can go directly to that route if they save some bookmarks of that page etc.)

To keep your object in the global place, you have different alternatives:

1. [Simple State Management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) (Simple/Basic implementation)
2. Using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want doing something like this:

Declare a new route:

```
{
  path: '/champion/:championKey',
  name: 'Some name',
  component: ChampionComponent,
}
```

Then, when redirecting to this new route:

```
redirectTo(champion) {
  this.$router.push("/champion/" + champion.key)
}
```

Now you can access to the url param like this:

```
this.$route.params.championKey // as declared in router.js
```

Comment: This way I can only get the champion key that is in URL, not the whole object. I thought it was possible to pass the whole object somehow, but apparently it isn't. I guess I have to do some logic in the mounted method of the  ChampionComponent to find the champion corresponding to the championKey in url, as @Ohgodwhy advised me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Oh you can, look you had to do -> this.$router.push("/champion/" + JSON.stringify(champion)) <- that will convert a json object into a string then when you retrieve it to convert it to json again you do JSON.parse(championKey) it will return a json from the string you recived from the route.params but it will look a little ugly

Comment: I meant the url, having a parsed json, it will look weird